# Create a Custom Symfony FormType Widget with a Multiple Word Name

Tags: forms, symfony

Symfony allows you to easily [customize, extend, or create your own form type widgets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). This works great if you want to name  your new form type 'foo'. However, if you want to name your custom type with **two words** like `fooBar`, how would you go about naming the PHP formType, the Service, and the Twig? There are plenty of examples of symfony core form types that are multiple words separated by underscore, e.g. `collection_item_widget`. But that doesn't work for custom form types.

So if you want to make a new form type called `fooBarType`, you would create a controller called `fooBarType.php`

```
class FooBarType extends AbstractType {
    public function getName() {
        return 'fooBar';
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

Set this as a service (optional):

```
cms.form.type.foo_bar:
    class: Cms\FooBundle\Form\Type\FooBar
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: fooBar }
```

Then customize the `fields.html.twig` and create a block for that named `foo_bar_widget` or `foobar_widget` or `fooBar_widget` (none of these work):

```
{% block foo_bar_widget %}
    {{ block('entity_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

*NOTE: If this is in a different location, you also have to register this in config.yml*

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'CmsFooBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Then use that field in a form builder, e.g.

```
$builder->add('myField', 'fooBar');
```

Everything works above, except the custom block in the fields.html.twig does not render, **unless** I change all the names to something simple like 'foo'.

¿Por Que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with my example was in the inconsistency of the camelCase starting in the service definition, as well as a problem in the twig template.

Technically, according to specs, the service should be lowercase and underscore, e.g. `cms.form.type.foo_bar`. And the twig widget definitions are also underscore, e.g. `collection_item_widget`. So although both camelCase and underscore work (if you are consistent in the widget, the getName() of the formType controller, and in the $formBuilder->add() function) it should probably always be underscore.

This works for me now:

**The Controller**

```
class FooBarType extends AbstractType {
    public function getName() {
        return 'foo_bar';
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

**The Service Definition**

```
cms.form.type.foo_bar:
    class: Cms\FooBundle\Form\Type\FooBar
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: foo_bar }
```

**The Usage in the Form Builder**

```
$builder->add('myField', 'foo_bar');
```

**The fields.html.twig** 
The fields.html.twig can be defined as camelCase (to match the alias). But there is no such thing as `block('entity_widget')` evidently. I *think* entity is just an extension of the choice widget. So my custom widget was loading, but no choices were present because that block was incorrect. It works if I change this to `choice_widget`:

```
{% block foo_bar_widget %}
    <!-- some customizations -->
    {{ block('choice_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note ahead: You don't have to define the form type as a service, if you don't have any parameters or other services you need to inject into the type. You can always call the form type directly in the form builder via:

```
$builder
    ->add('foo_bar_field', new FooBarType());
```

Anyway, I just did a quick test using the gender type example from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and it worked fine for me.

These are the settings i used:

Type class **Jahller\TestBundle\Form\Type\GenderDoType.php**

```
namespace Jahller\TestBundle\Form\Type;

// ...

class GenderDoType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'genderDo';
    }
}
```

Service definition **Jahller/TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
jahller.form.type.gender:
        class: Jahller\TestBundle\Form\Type\GenderDoType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: genderDo }
```

Type twig template **Jahller/TestBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig**

```
{% block genderDo_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if expanded %}
            <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {% for child in form %}
                    <li>
                        {{ form_widget(child) }}
                        {{ form_label(child) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            {# just let the choice widget render the select tag #}
            {{ block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Form class with type include **Jahller\TestBundle\Form\TestType.php**

```
namespace Jahller\TestBundle\Form;

// ...

class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender_code', 'genderDo', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a gender',
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // ...   
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Type rendered:

[image]

Maybe you can find something in my code you did differently.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I had was with the double word, not knowing whether to do underscores or camelCase. But I see you did camelCase `genderDo_widget` and it worked, so that's great confirmation (it's not mentioned in the documentation so hopefully that helps others). Maybe when I was testing various options I had combination wrong, e.g. defining the service as foo_bar instead of fooBar (as my example shows). I'll have to try again.

Comment: I found the problem (and you avoided it in your example by calling your service `jahller.form.type.gender` instead of `jahller.form.type.gender_do`). The problem was caused by me using an underscore in the service name, when for consistency I guess it has to be camelCase `jahller.form.type.genderDo` (although I thought that wasn't allowed).